# How to display multiple values in the same cell in a DataTable

Tags: javascript, datatables

I'm having trouble showing several values from different fields in the database in the datatable. The code I have from the table is:

```
var listar = function () {
var table = $('#customers-table-view').DataTable({
destroy: true,
ajax: {
    method: 'POST',
    url: 'listar'
},
columns: [
    ...
    {'data': 'service1'},
    ...
],
```

In the database I have service1, service2, service3 ... on or off. What I would like is to get those values in the same column. That is to say that in the cell something like that remained; On, Off, Off ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to display a custom value on DataTables column, you might want to use the [`columns.render`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.render) property. You can pass a function that returns a text or even an HTML element.

On your case, this might look something like this:

```
$('#customers-table-view').DataTable({
  columns: [
    ...
    { 
      data: 'service1',
      render: function (data, type, row, meta) {
        return row.service1 + ', ' + row.service2 + ', ' + row.service3
      }
    },
    ...
  ]
});
```

Hope this gives you an idea.